# Combining differential equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone see how to combine the following 3 equations

$$\dot r^2-\dot\theta^2=-\theta^2$$
$$\theta\ddot \theta-2\dot \theta^2=2(\dot r^2-\dot \theta^2)$$
$$\dot r=a \theta^2$$
to get $$\theta^2=r^2+cr+d$$
where $c,d$ are constants?

I've tried various ways of substituting one into another but I just end up with very high orders of derivatives, solving of which I don't think should be necessary.

What I did was (2)-(1) then substitute in (3), giving
$$(a-1)\theta^2=\theta\ddot\theta-\dot\theta^2$$
So I need the RHS to be $$(a-1)r^2+Ar+B$$ for some constants $A,B$? But how??

or perhaps start differently?

Comment: Combining the first equation and the last one, you can get $(1+1/a)\dot{r}^2=\dot{\theta}^2$. Taking the square root and integrating should lead you to the relation you need.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: Thanks for your comment, however, i don't think $(1+1/a)\dot r^2=\dot \theta^2$. Shouldn't it be $\dot r^2-(1/a)\dot r+\dot \theta^2=0$?

Comment: Woops, you are right, I misread the last equation. However, this could still work, I think however that the equation should be $\dot r^2+(1/a)\dot r-\dot \theta^2=0$

Comment: Could you give some background about the origin of the equations? that would be helpful.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: Hmm, the previous bits are takn from a physics question. But I am sure that it boils downto these 3 equations only!

Comment: Just state the original physics problem. Was it given as a Lagrangian?

Comment: @Raskolnikov: Sure, sorry about the delay. For a 2 dimensional space such that $$ds^2=\frac{1}{\theta^2}(-d\theta^2+dr^2)$$
the timelike geodesics are given by $$\theta^2=r^2+cr+d$$ where $a,b$ are constants.

Comment: Hmmm... how come you have three geodesic equations then? Shouldn't you just have two? In particular, what's the origin of the first equation?

Comment: Is the first one maybe just a rewriting of the metric?

Comment: @Raskolnikov: Yes, indeed. It is just incorporating the "timelike" property of the geodesic.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: Btw, I really appreciate your preservering with this. :)

Comment: There's an unnecessary factor $2$ in your second equation on the right hand side i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the solution. You only need the first equation and the third one.

First, note that

$$\frac{d\theta}{dr}=\frac{\dot\theta}{\dot r} \; .$$

Then, divide the first equation by ${\dot r}^2$ to get

$$1-\frac{\dot\theta^2}{\dot r^2}=-\frac{\theta^2}{\dot r^2}$$

Using the third equation and rearranging, you can transform this to

$$1+\frac{1}{a^2\theta^2}=\left(\frac{d\theta}{dr}\right)^2$$

Take the square root and you can easily integrate by separation of variables to give the sought result.

Comment: THANK UUUUU!! how on earth did u see that? thanks again!

Comment: I realized that the easiest way to solve this would be to make an equation for $\theta$ in terms of $r$. So I started to figure out the first and second derivative of $\theta$ w.r.t. $r$. But I then got stuck on the second equation. Until it dawned on me that I didn't even need it. The first and third would be enough and that's when it rolled out.

Comment: I also had a strange feeling of déjà-vu. As if I had done or seen that problem before. Which is also why I asked you for the context.

Comment: Awesome stuff! :)